# Scroll To bottom of element on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scroll

I'm looking to achieve the effect of clicking an anchor tag and it scrolling to element on the page.

I already have this with [jquery scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/). Like so:

```
$.scrollTo( this.hash, 1500, {
    easing:'easeInOutCubic',
    'axis':'y'
});
```

However, I need to it align it so that the element sits at the bottom of the viewport when it's finished animating. Each section on the page is a different height so it would need to dynamically get the elements position and height I guess.

I'm having difficulty working out what numbers I need to calculate to achieve this.

**EDIT**

I have changed it to this now

```
var section = $(this.hash);

var scrollPos = $(section).offset().top + ( $(window).height() - $(section).height() );

$('html, body').scrollTop( scrollPos );
```

But this is still wrong, the '#about' section is now halfway up the page on click, rather than aligned at the bottom of the viewport.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: That is what I already have. I need it to scroll so the element is at the bottom of the viewport rather than the top.

Comment: @ChrisTill can you give a fiddle for what you have right now?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9XB8h/5/

Comment: it doesnt work because you should subtract window height not add it. check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. get height of the element [$(element).height()](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https://api.jquery.com/height/&ei=hvMlU7WiCOn8ygO4toCABg&usg=AFQjCNHultDjg27j4qzC2XJ7II4KcfHN1g&sig2=bBmguwnXQuhdhRz4XsRJlg&bvm=bv.62922401,d.bGQ)
2. get viewport's height [$(window).height()](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https://api.jquery.com/height/&ei=hvMlU7WiCOn8ygO4toCABg&usg=AFQjCNHultDjg27j4qzC2XJ7II4KcfHN1g&sig2=bBmguwnXQuhdhRz4XsRJlg&bvm=bv.62922401,d.bGQ)
3. get top position of the element [$(element).offset().top](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)
4. scroll page to $(element).offset().top - ( $(window).height() -
   $(element).height() )

Comment: document height wont work as the document can be miles long. has to be window height

Comment: I've updated my code with this (See question) but it still doent calculate the correct height

Comment: The correct number to scroll to is 520. your solution gives me 8xx

Comment: sorry, typo. Subtraction is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var section = $(this.hash);
var scrollPos = section.offset().top + section.height() - $(window).height();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9XB8h/7/)

Answer (score 0):

there is answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element) that shows how to scroll page so that the selected element aligns to the top of window.

as for your request to align it to the bottom, i have corrected the code from the linked post:

all you have to do basically is to subtract the window height, and the element height as follows:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#wmd-input").offset().top - $("#wmd-input").height() - $(window).height()
}, 2000)
```

the #wmd-input element from my example is the answer text area from this page, open developer console in your browser, paste the code and see it in work

(or any other question where you have the answer area available)