# Implement element.scrollIntoView with scrollTo

Tags: javascript

How to implement

```
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: "end", inline: "nearest"})
```

using `widnow.scrollTo({behavior: 'smooth', top: ??})`?

I have created some [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-satoshi-5knbmb). I need to scroll exactly the same position as using `scrollIntoView`

Comment: Safari doesn't support smooth scrolling on `.scrollTo()` either according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo#browser_compatibility). If you click the asterisk on the support table it displays:  "Safari does not have support for the smooth scroll behavior."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Workaround: Smooth scrolling without the CSS property Scroll Behavior: Smooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814404/ios-workaround-smooth-scrolling-without-the-css-property-scroll-behavior-smoot)

Comment: @DBS you're right, smooth doesn't work in Safari...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22441309) answer

```
const targetEl = document.getElementById('target');
 
window.scrollTo({
  behavior: 'smooth', 
  top: targetEl.offsetTop + targetEl.clientHeight - window.innerHeight
})
```